# tensorflow wide model: how to use one-hot feature?

Tags: tensorflow

I have read about the model in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/wide_and_deep/index.html
the feature in article has two type: Categorical and Continuous

In my case, I have a column which describe the userid ,range from 0 to 10000000

I treat this column as Categorical and use hash-bucket , but only get a pool auc value about 0.50010

1)is it need to use one-hot to process this id column?

2)if it's needed, how to achieve this?  I find a "tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_encoding" ,but it's not support column names so cannot be used in wide-n-deep demo.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to encode the UserID column. Each value is unique and is not a Categorical value. It makes sense to one-hot-encode when there are less than 1000 categories.

To answer your question on how to use the one_hot_encoding, assuming you have a list of labels (note that they must be integers):

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    labels = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    labels_t = tf.constant(labels)
    num_classes = len(labels)

    one_hot = tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_encoding(labels_t, num_classes=num_classes)
    print(one_hot.eval())
```

Comment: so your advise is that use one-hot for a huge range column ?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/wide_and_deep/index.htmlin tflearn lib , a model fit with columns, but one-hot type is not supported "linear_feature_columns=wide_columns"